# FluentValidation multiple validators for a single command

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I am currently struggling with a scenario where I use MediatR with FluentValidation. 
I try to have two validators for a single command. 
The first validator should validate if all properties are correcly given.
The second one should do some business logic validation like if is there already an entry with this value. 
 
It is important that the second validator is called only if the first one is already finished and has no errors.

Here is the demo code I currently have.

Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Demo")]
public class DemoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public DemoController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] DemoCommand command)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.Errors.Any())
            return BadRequest(response.Errors);

        return Ok(response.Result);
    }
}
```

Command

```
public class DemoCommand : IRequest<Response>
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string SomeValue { get; }

    public DemoCommand(int id, string someValue)
    {
        Id = id;
        SomeValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Validation

```
public class DemoCommandValidation : AbstractValidator<DemoCommand>
{
    public DemoCommandValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeValue)
           .NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

CommandHandler

```
public class DemoCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DemoCommand, Response>
{
    public Task<Response> Handle(DemoCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do someting
        return Task.FromResult(new Response());
    }
}
```

Response Model

```
public class Response
{
    private readonly IList<string> _messages = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; }
    public object Result { get; }

    public Response() => Errors = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_messages);

    public Response(object result) : this() => Result = result;

    public Response AddError(string message)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
        return this;
    }
}
```

ValidationBehavior

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
     where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse> where TResponse : Response
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var failures = _validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(request))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        return failures.Any()
            ? Errors(failures)
                : next();
    }

    private static Task<TResponse> Errors(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> failures)
    {
        var response = new Response();

        foreach (var failure in failures)
        {
            response.AddError(failure.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(response as TResponse);
    }
}
```

Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;

        AssemblyScanner
            .FindValidatorsInAssembly(assembly)
                .ForEach(result => services.AddScoped(result.InterfaceType, result.ValidatorType));

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));

        services.AddMediatR(assembly);

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the second validator still being called if the first one has errors? You've told us the expected output, which is good, but you haven't told us how it is currently behaving.

Comment: @GregBurghardt the best behavior would be if the first validator has any errors than the api should return the errors from the first validator and dont call the second one or the command handler.